# How to use 'OR' keyword in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is the code below correct? I want to retrieve a list of DataFiles for the given DataNum and if the datacodes are either 2 or 3.

```
public List<DataFileVO> getDataFileByDataNum(String dataNum) {

 List<DataFileVO> DataFileList = new ArrayList<DataFileVO>();

    String query = "select datafile from DataFileVO datafile "
            + "where datafile.dataNum = ?"
            + "and datafile.dataRetrievalTypeCode = 2 OR duadatafile.dataFileRetrievalTypeCode = 3";

    DataFileList = this.getHibernateTemplate().find(query, dataNum);

    return DataFileList;
```

Comment: First check is "datafile.dataRetrievalTypeCode = 1", second is "duadatafile.dataFileRetrievalTypeCode = 3". Are you really looking for "2" and "3"? Are those really different objects and fields? Otherwise you are probably just missing brackets around your OR clause.

Comment: Ohh wait, I meant 2 and 3. @Marvin. Where do I add the brackets again? and (datafile.dataRetrievalTypeCode = 2 OR duadatafile.dataFileRetrievalTypeCode = 3"). Is that right?

Comment: Assuming your object and field names are correct: Yes.

Comment: I can see a few problems already. Please post your error output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
and datafile.dataRetrievalTypeCode = 2 OR duadatafile.dataFileRetrievalTypeCode = 3
```

By:

```
and datafile.dataRetrievalTypeCode in(2,3)
```

This is what you are trying to do. Cheers!